# React simulator ios native

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to leave this here for future me.

When this error occurs make sure you check the code:

```
 /bin/sh -c /Users/jvilchis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/greatreact-dkbvpjswqresoybydivatvcctnaa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-5F4C70EF7D90A5A5BDAEB404279F232A.sh
nvm is not compatible with the "npm_config_prefix" environment variable: currently set to "/usr/local"
Run `unset npm_config_prefix` to unset it.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the greatreact editor. (in target 'greatreact' from project 'greatreact')

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/jvilchis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/greatreact-dkbvpjswqresoybydivatvcctnaa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-5F4C70EF7D90A5A5BDAEB404279F232A.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Check the simulator version, build a simulator to deploy the build for.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time these messages happen when I use a different iOS Simulator. I have notice that when I run my code on simulator iPhone 11 Pro, most of the time works. When I deploy to iPhone 13 iOS 15.4 it breaks. Also, I have been removing the node_modules folder, deleting the package-lock.json and running  `npm install` 
then installing the pods by:
`cd ios pods install`

after that, I open the project in xcode and run the app.

this is for future me, but please use these notes to make your app work. I'm planning on using this to note most of the issues I have been having with my app build.